# Out Of Memory exception if files to big

Tags: asp.net, out-of-memory

I'm currently working on a data-check for images. I need to request the Size (width & height) and the resolution of the image. Files over 70MB throw an "out of memory" exception on GDI Problem. Is there an alternative way to get the file-information? The same error on parse it through FromStream...

```
Using myfile = Image.FromFile(filePath)
...
End Using
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to get image properties (it loads metadata only):

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Dmitry\Pictures\blue-earth-wallpaper.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
   var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
   var size = decoder.Frames[0].PixelWidth;
   var height = decoder.Frames[0].PixelHeight;
   var dpiX = decoder.Frames[0].DpiX;
   var dpiY = decoder.Frames[0].DpiY;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of Decoders in .NET as I said before. This version of code chooses the right one automatically and works with all .net recognizable file formats.

Comment: You are right but I forgot to say that it's an simple website-project. The WPF Handler doesn't work on this or am i'm wrong?

Comment: Any idea why the resolution of TIF-Files is in the most cases 96dpi instead the real resolution?

Comment: I would suggest to create a new question. I think it makes PC computers (not Mac) render it in a pixel to pixel mode (1 picture pixel maps to 1 screen pixel). Real resolution was lost at the moment of image file creation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link http://www.fastgraph.com/help/image_file_header_formats.html that tells where in the file you can find the type and its dimensions. I guess, if you use something like this below to seek and get the first few bytes and close once you are done, shouldnt be using much resources

Untested code below...

```
//  This really needs to be a member-level variable;
private static readonly object fsLock = new object();
//  Instantiate this in a static constructor or initialize() method
private static FileStream fs = new FileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open);


public string ReadFile(int fileOffset) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int arrayOffset = 0;

    lock (fsLock) {
        fs.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        int numBytesRead = fs.Read(bytes, arrayOffset , bufferSize);

        //  Typically used if you're in a loop, reading blocks at a time
        arrayOffset += numBytesRead;
    }

    // Do what you want to the byte array and close

}
```

Comment: The resolution of the images is important. These function won't let me access to that. Thank you.